# Change datetime into javascript utc format

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a function that groups availabilities by day. The last availability of a day is on 22:00 to 23:00. But since the summer time two weeks ago, the last availability is in the group of the next day.

```
var dateTime= new Date(availability.BeginDateTime);
var beginDateTimeTimeMilliseconds = dateUtilities.extractDate(dateTime).getTime();

if (!groupedByDay[beginDateTimeTimeMilliseconds ]) {
  availabilityTimeSlotsGroupedByDay[beginDateTimeTimeMilliseconds ] = [availability];
}  else {
  groupedByDay[beginDateTimeTimeMilliseconds ].push(availability);
}

return groupedByDay;
```

I think I can correct this with the utc function of javascript. How I can change this format "2015-04-09T14:00:00" into a utc time format?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
var utcDate = new Date(datetime).toISOString();
```

or

```
var utcDate = new Date(datetime.getTime() + datetime.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
```

Comment: I have tried both options, but it was not successful.

Comment: @user3679607:- What is the result which you are getting with the two options?

Comment: With the first one (the iso string) it is the same. The last availability is also in the false day group. And the second one doesn't go, because it is false code

Answer (score 0):

@Rahul Tripathi:

What I tried was following:

```
var fromDateTimeMilliSeconds = new Date(availability.BeginDateTime).toISOString();
if (!availabilityTimeSlotsGroupedByDay[fromDateTimeMilliseconds]) {
  availabilityTimeSlotsGroupedByDay[fromDateTimeMilliseconds] = [availabilityTimeSlot];
} else {
  availabilityTimeSlotsGroupedByDay[fromDateTimeMilliseconds].push(availabilityTimeSlot);
}

return availabilityTimeSlotsGroupedByDay;
```

And the second option:

```
var fromDateTimeMilliSeconds = new Date(availability.BeginDateTime.getTime() + availability.gettimezoneOffset() * 60000);
if (!availabilityTimeSlotsGroupedByDay[fromDateTimeMilliseconds]) {
  availabilityTimeSlotsGroupedByDay[fromDateTimeMilliseconds] = [availabilityTimeSlot];
} else {
  availabilityTimeSlotsGroupedByDay[fromDateTimeMilliseconds].push(availabilityTimeSlot);
}

return availabilityTimeSlotsGroupedByDay;
```

With the first option I got the same result. The last availability of the day was also in the false group by day.
And the second option wasn't successful, I got an error.